# AWS - Send Custom Parameters from an Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I have a number of AWS Alarms setup in CloudWatch. When one of these alarms is tripped, I currently send a notification to ServiceNow. I would like to send some custom parameters in this notification, something like:

```
{
  "source":"machineName",
  "dataUrl": "someUrl"
}
```

My challenge is, I do not see a way to add custom parameters via the AWS Console for an alarm. Is there a way for me to send custom parameters to an SNS topic that will get sent to the target from an AWS CloudWatch Alarm?